# StringHttpMessageConverter to use Mediate type "application/gml+xml"

Tags: json, spring, hibernate

I am trying to use @JsonSerialize annotation in Spring and then serialize GML string so that the string will be displayed in MediaType "application/gml+xml" where the gml tags can be expanded and collapsed. I think I can achieve this using StringHttpMessageConverter in spring 3. Does anyone have experience using this. I am not sure how to get this working. Can anyone suggest something please?